# Order of before_save callbacks in rails

Tags: activerecord

I am trying to geocode an address and I am trying to geocode on a non-persistent attribute called full_address. Here is my code:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Dirty

  validates :name, :organization, :title, :state, :city, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i, }

  before_save :full_address
  geocoded_by :full_address

  before_save :geocode, if: ->(obj){obj.full_address.present? && (obj.city_changed? || obj.state_changed?)}

  def full_address
    "#{city}, #{state}"
  end
end
```

￼
I am not sure if my before_save callbacks are firing the in the right order. Basically, how do I make sure the

```
before_save :full_address
```

fires before the other?

I looked into the around_save documentation, but I am still unsure what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jwan --

AR callbacks are used for a lot of reasons, and they are particularly helpful for dealing with records in the DB, but you don't need one here for for 'full_address'.  Why?

Because all it is it doing is returning a string, not performing an operation on the db or altering data in any way.

It's been awhile since I've worked with `geocoder` gem, but in your other before_save callback, you are passing a lambdha for conditional operation.

Couple things:

1.) You're checking for presence of an interpolated string, but validating presence of the two interpolated attributes, which fires before the callback, so `obj.full_address.present?` should always return `true` because it will blow up on the validations if both or even one of those attributes isn't present.  Try

`before_save :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.city_changed? || obj.state_changed? }`

+1 though on ActiveModel::Dirty implementation!

2.) Unless you're using a much older version of Rails or explicitly configuring it otherwise, `ActiveModel::Dirty` is autoloaded; no need for `line 2`.

3.) I would also try using an after_validation callback instead of the before_save.  Can't guarantee that will solve the problem, but it is earlier in the callback stack.  Refer to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html